# WebGL how to render 3d array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, opengl-es, webgl

I'm trying to figure out a good way to render mathematical functions using WebGL. Or just everything that I put in an array, like basic mathematical functions. So here I just put some 3D coordinate in an array, it does not seem to work.

This are my code lines:

> arrays.js [UPDATED]

```
var myPosArray = [];
var myArrBuffer = null;
var x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
/*Function that fills the array*/
function dotter() {
    myArrBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, myArrBuffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        x = Math.cos(i * Math.PI / 3);
        y = Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 4);
        z = x + y;
        myPosArray.push(x);
        myPosArray.push(y);
        myPosArray.push(z);
    }
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(myPosArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    myArrBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    myArrBuffer.numItems = myPosArray.lenght / 3;

}
/*This function is supposed to draw the points*/
function drawPoints(){
        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0,
                pMatrix);
//      mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
        /*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
        /*Draw triangle*/
        mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [ -1.5, 0.0, -7.0 ]);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, myArrBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, myArrBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, myArrBuffer.numItems);
}
```

shaders:

> i set up the shaders here [UPDATED]:

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
 precision mediump float;

  varying vec4 vColor;

  void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0);
  }
</script>
<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
  attribute vec4 aVertexColor;

  uniform mat4 mvMatrix;
  uniform mat4 pMatrix;

  varying vec4 vColor;

  void main(void) {
    gl_Position = pMatrix * mvMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
  }
</script>
```

> schaders.js

```
/* Setting shaders up */
/* +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ */
function getShader(gl, id) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!shaderScript) {
        return null;
    }
    var str = "";
    var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
    while (k) {
        if (k.nodeType == 3) {
            str += k.textContent;
        }
        k = k.nextSibling;
    }
    var shader;
    if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
    gl.compileShader(shader);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        return null;
    }
    return shader;
}
var shaderProgram;
function lightingShaders(){
     shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "pMatrix");
     shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mvMatrix");

}
function initShaders() {
    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");
    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    }
    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram,"aVertexPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

    lightingShaders();
}
```

Comment: I haven't looked through all of it, but why are you declaring `mvmatrix` and `pMatrix` but using `uPMatrix` and `uMVMatrix` in your vertex shader?

Comment: Ok, I tought I changed it everywhere, thank you for pointing this out. But still not working...

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: I can see the canvas, the background is black but I can't see any points?

Comment: The only other thing I can see offhand is a misspelled `length` in the last line of `dotter()`. What does the error console say?

Comment: So I rebooted the server and cleaned it, and now I got this error: 'Error: WebGL: drawArrays: bound vertex attribute buffers do not have sufficient size for given first and count'

Comment: I think I've been getting distracted by the `lenght` typo... Why is `myArrBuffer.itemSize = 4;` when you have 3 coordinates per vertex?

Comment: Ok so itemSize = 3 because we have 3 coordinates, numItems = myPosArray.length/3. I still only got the black canva...

Comment: Your code says `"itemSize = 4"`

Comment: itemSize is up to date now

Comment: I added the shaders.js as well, there where some errors to correct. But still no points on screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, there were some small errors, but I think the real problem here is that you didn't set the matrix uniforms before you call `gl.drawArrays`. I assume you're following the tutorials on http://learningwebgl.com/, so the last 3 lines in `drawPoints()` should be:

```
gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, 
                       myArrBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
setMatrixUniforms();
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, myArrBuffer.numItems);
```

where `setMatrixUniforms()` is defined as:

```
function setMatrixUniforms() {
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
}
```

Note that I also changed `gl.vertexAttribArray` to `gl.vertexAttribPointer`.

Using the translation matrix

```
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [ 0.0, 0.0, -7.0 ]);
```

and setting the point size to 10 in the vertex shader for visibility

```
gl_PointSize = 10.0;
```

here's the output I got:

[image: WebGL screenshot]